# Registro no Banco de Dados MySQL 8.0 com PHP 8.0.5

Tags: php, mysql

Fala galera!

Eu sou iniciante em PHP e não estou conseguindo inserir dados no meu banco de dados MySQL.

Segue o meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>Exemplo PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo "<h1>Adição de usuário</h1>";
        $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ' ');
        if(!$conexao) {
            echo "<p><b>Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados</b></p>";
            echo mysqli_error();
        }
        else {
            mysqli_select_db('db_exemplo', $conexao);
            $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO usuarios(Usuario, Senha) VALUES ('ADMIN','SENHA')");
            if(!$sql)
                echo "<h2>Não foi possível cadastrar o usuário!</h2>";
            else 
                echo "<h2>Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!</h2>";
        }
        mysqli_close($conexao);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Quando eu abro a página no navegador, ela me retorna somente "Adição de usuário" e também já realizei a consulta no banco e não aconteceu nenhum registro.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pedro, está faltando vc passar o conector na função `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)`

Deixe desta forma que vai funcionar:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO usuarios(Usuario, Senha) VALUES ('ADMIN','SENHA')");
```

Comment: Rafael, muito obrigado! Você me deu uma luz. Da forma como você me orientou, ainda continuava não me retornando nada, o que eu fiz foi o seguinte, aonde é feita a conexão com o banco eu alterei para `$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ' ', 'db_exemplo');` em seguida eliminei a linha `mysqli_select_db('db_exemplo', $conexao);` e passei o conector para a função `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)` e funcionou.

Comment: Perfeito, @Pedro. Um dos parâmetros que o `mysqli_connect()` recebe é o banco de dados, no caso, o seu `db_exemplo`. Na dúvida, acessa o manual e os exemplos. Pode não resolver mas lança alguma luz no problema.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php